# Pandas read_csv python engine read gbk csv file error

Tags: python, pandas

i want use pandas(read_csv) to parse a csv file( gbk(chinese character), multiple delimiter), but the result is not correct,
my test file:
[image]

my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("./test1.txt", header=None, delimiter=",@,", names=["col_01", "col_02", "col_03"], encoding="GBK", engine="python")
print df
```

result( only the first row is correct):

[image]

Comment: can you copy-paste the content(or part of it) of your file into the question instead of posting a screenshot?

Comment: the second column is a chinese character(gbk):    你好

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like the file is already broken. I just checked with a file that has the character you have pasted here and it works just fine for multiple rows. Can you check that your file is not broken after the first row

Comment: the file is correct, it's a gbk character file , my ssh terminal's character encoding is utf8, so it can't be  displayed correctly